Expected stopping time for Brownian motion without drift, conditional on a certain point is hit sometime before stopping
Assume that $a<c<0<b$ and $B(0)=0$.
I am looking for the expected stopping time given that $B$ hits $c$ at some point before it hits any of the boundaries.
I guess this is expressed as
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau_c]$$ such that
$$\tau_c = \min\{t : B(t) \in \{a, b\}| \exists t_c:(0<t_c\leq t) \wedge(B(t_c)=c)\}.$$
To clarify, I don't care how many times $c$ is crossed or which exit $B$ takes. I know that any exit through $a$ satisfies the condition but paths exiting through $b$ does not necessarily include $c$.
What is the best way to approach such a problem?
I am actually looking for "time spent in an interval conditional", i.e., expected stopping time if we know $B$ spent $t_1$ within $[c,d]$, but I guess this question is a good stepping stone.
Thanks in advance!

It seems to me that your idea is better described by the conditional expectation $E[\tau_a\wedge \tau_b|\tau_c<\tau_a\wedge \tau_b]$.

@Snoop I am not sure, but I am also not very educated in BM nomenclature. What is $\tau_c$ here? Also, why do you separately define $\tau_a$ and $\tau_b$?

$\tau_p$ is the first hitting time of $p\in\mathbb{R}$. Separating $\tau_a,\tau_b$ is sometimes convenient in these problems.

@Snoop feel free to edit the question if you think it would make it more accurate and easier to understand :)

We know that at one point in time, $B$ would hit $c$. Thus, we can separate the expected time to hit into two:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau_c] = \mathbb{E}[\tau_{c1}] + \mathbb{E}[\tau_{c2}], 
$$
where $\tau_{c1}$ is the time to hit $c$ given that it has not yet hit $b$ and $\tau_{c2}$ is the time to hit either $a$ or $b$, starting from $c$.
$\tau_{c1}$ comes directly from this question, i.e.,
$$
\tau_{c1} = \frac{-c}{3}\times (2b-c).
$$
$\tau_{c2}$ is the regular hitting time. Shifting the boundaries $-c$ units to right, such that $B(0)=0$, we have
$$
\tau_{c2} = (c-a)\times (b-c).
$$
So,
$$ \tau_c = \frac{-c}{3}\times (2b-c) + (c-a)\times (b-c)
$$
For $a = -4$, $b = 3$ and $c=-1$, $\tau_c = 14.33$. I did a Monte Carlo simulation for 40000 trials, with $\Delta{x} = 0.01$ and obtained $\tau_c = 14.308$. 10118 of the 40000 trials ended up at $b$ without touching $c$.
This question was definitely not a starting point for my eventual aims.
